# How to put php variable in img src?

Tags: php, html, pdo

I don't know why it doesn't work  I am trying to view profile image. the path is in database and `$data['pic']` shows the path but I think the syntax is wrong  Thx in advance :)

```
<img src="/images/<?php echo $data['pic']->pic_path; ?>">
```

This is `var_dump($data['pic'])`   as you see you see `pic_path` has a value in it

```
object(Profile_model)#3 (12) { ["user_id"]=> NULL ["username"]=> NULL ["f_name"]=> NULL ["l_name"]=> NULL ["phone"]=> NULL ["email"]=> NULL ["address"]=> NULL ["height"]=> NULL ["weight"]=> NULL ["goal"]=> NULL ["_connection":protected]=> object(PDO)#4 (0) { } ["pic_path"]=> object(Profile_model)#8 (12) { ["user_id"]=> NULL ["username"]=> NULL ["f_name"]=> NULL ["l_name"]=> NULL ["phone"]=> NULL ["email"]=> NULL ["address"]=> NULL ["height"]=> NULL ["weight"]=> NULL ["goal"]=> NULL ["_connection":protected]=> object(PDO)#9 (0) { } ["pic_path"]=> string(27) "5caf5df7b2ee68.41908466.jpg" } }
```

```
<img src="/images/<?php echo $data['pic']->pic_path; ?>">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you provided in your question, I can see that `$data['pic']->pic_path` is an object of type `Profile_model`, and inside of it, there is another property `'pic_path'` which is, in fact, a string. So I believe `$data['pic']->pic_path->pic_path` would give you the path, but I suspect this is **not** the intended behavior.
I would suggest you double check how an object is being assigned to the first `$data['pic']->pic_path`.

Comment: You raise a good point about the original assigment to `$data['pic']->pic_path`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment, now it finally works but why pic_path is an object? is it because how I sent to view ?

Comment: $this->view('profile/index_profile', ['profile'=>$profile,'pic'=>$pic]);

Comment: This is how I sent the data from controller to view

Comment: I wouldn't say it has to do with the way you send it to the view (suspect you are using Laravel). It is more what value `$pic` is being assigned before being sent to the view. If you can update your question with the controller code I can try to help you with that.